# Accessing ssl server (web service) from .net client

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, keystore, truststore

I’m tryng to access a ssl server (web service) from a .net client (c#). I have access to a java client code that can connect to the server. Included in the source code are 3 files (saPubKey.jks, WebServices.pfx and trustStore) and I think that only 2 of the 3 are used in the java example.

```
private void setSSLConnection(WSBindingProvider bp){
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
    ks.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("WebServices.pfx"), "password".toCharArray());

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    kmf.init(ks, "password".toCharArray());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ts.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("trustStore"), "pass".toCharArray());

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    tmf.init(ts);
    sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

    bp.getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslContext.getSocketFactory());

}
```

The code I have for the c# client is this

```
var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\WebServices.pfx", "password");
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://blablabla.org:700/fws/ftrs");
req.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);
req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"https://blablabla.org:700/fws/ftrs/Rgdvice\"");
req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
req.Accept = "text/xml";
req.Method = "POST";
using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
{
   using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
   {
      stmw.Write(soap);
   }
}
WebResponse response = req.GetResponse(); //(500) Internal Server Error.
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Method req.GetResponse() throws "(500) Internal Server Error."
With no client certificates added I get: "An unexpected error occurred on a send."
I also tried this line of code with no luck:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

I'm new to ssl and certificates, and really need help accessing the ssl server from c#.

Answer (score 0):

This could be unrelated but make sure web service is not in the app_code folder.